# Shrink a frame on a canvas, when the children of the frame are removed

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, frame

I have scrollable widgets on frame. The frame is on a canvas. It is a console and the clear console button calls

```
for i in self.CanvasFrame.winfo_children():
     i.destroy()
```

The CanvasFrame is the frame which is on the canvas and has it's children destroyed. The problem is, when the children are gone, the size of the frame remains and the event to configure the canvas doesn't work because of the remained size. The event handler:

```
self.update()
self.Canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.Canvas.bbox("all"))
self.Canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)
```

I tried to

```
self.Canvas.itemconfigure(1, height = 0) #didnt work
self.Canvas.itemconfigure(1, height = 1)
```

The other line gives it a fixed height and adding new children wont resize the frame. How should I solve this problem ?

UPDATE:
Working clear console method:

```
for i in self.CanvasFrame.winfo_children():
    i.destroy()
Label(self.CanvasFrame).pack()
self.CanvasConfigureEvent()
self.CanvasFrame.winfo_children()[0].destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove all of the widgets from another widget such as a frame, no geometry manager is in control anymore. Since no geometry manager is in control, the frame is never instructed to resize.

The simplest solution is to create a 1x1 frame or label and pack that in the frame, at least temporarily. That will cause the pack algorithm to kick in and resize the parent frame.